# php query ldap records including date/timestamp field

Tags: php, ldap

Is it possible to run a php query in ldap that gets the createTimestamp or modifyTimestamp fields?  I have not had any luck.

The code below returns everything but those two fields.

```
if(@$info[$i]['mail']['0']) {
                $dateCreate = $info[$i]['createTimestamp ']['0'];
                $dateModify = $info[$i]['modifyTimestamp']['0'];
                $email =  $info[$i]['mail']['0'];
                $firstname =  $info[$i]['givenname']['0'];
                $lastname = $info[$i]['sn']['0'];
                $officeName = $info[$i]['physicaldeliveryofficename']['0'];
                echo $dateCreate.",".$dateModify.",".$firstname.",".$lastname.",".$email.",".$department.",".$title."---".$officeName."<br />";
```

Thanks in advance.  I'll take any assistance including "look here" or "you are forgetting..."
Peter T

Comment: `"createTimeStamp is a constructed attribute, which typically cannot be used as part of the LDAP search filter."` and `"createTimeStamp is a constructed attribute which means that it doesn't exist in the database but gets "calculated" by the directory server "on the fly" by the time it gets queries."` - might be pertinent. Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2803f390-2355-4089-a9f0-9b89b0e0a22b/active-directory-ldap-attribute-createtimestamp-in-windows-server-2008-r2?forum=winserverDS

Answer (score 0):

In your `ldap_serch`-call you can add an array of retrieved attributes as 4th parameter. When you add a `+` as one of the parameters all the meta-attributes should be available as well.

```
$result = ldap_search($ldap, 'dc=example,dc=org', 'uid=doejane', ['cn', '+']);
var_dump(ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result));
```

And one of them (at least in my case) is the `modifytimestamp`